# C: size of *array[x]?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, indexing

I have a question that should be fairly straightforward (I hope).

In c, the size of an array delcared as `int array[10][10];`,

for example, I understand as having 10 spots in which to store 10 integers. However, what's the size of an array declared as `int *array[10];`? I know that `*array` has 10 elements, but how many elements does `array` have?

This is a hole in my understanding I would really like to clear up. Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's simply an array of `10` pointers. More specifically, and array of 10 `int*`.

Comment: "I know that `*array` has 10 elements"  --  Actually, `*array` is a pointer and not an array so it doesn't have elements.

Comment: Also consider `int (*array)[10]` which is a pointer to an array of 10 `int`s, so `*array` is an array of 10 `int`s.

Comment: Ah, okay, I think this is where my misconception lies

Comment: this expression: `int *array[10];` is declaring an array of 10 pointers to integers.  I.E. an array of pointers.  However, those pointers have not been initialized.  So need to add code to initialize each of those 10 pointers with the address of an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand the declaration in C.
Start dividing it in parts:

```
int array[10][10];
```

`array` is the name of the variable, the part `[10]` means that it is an array of 10 arrays of int, each array holding 10 elements (the second `[10]`).

Now:

```
int * array[10];
```

`array` is the name of the variable, the part `[10]` means that it is an array of 10 elements of type `int *` (**integer pointers not integers as before**).

The sizes in the firs case will be 10 times the size of an array of 10 integers = the space required for 100 integers.

In the second case will be the size to hold 10 pointers to integer.

As side note maybe your confusion comes from the fact that C allows access to elements of both declaration in the same way. I.e. the following will get the 5th integer of the second array:

```
int b = array[2][5];
```

But the difference remains substantial because in the first declaration the compiler will allocate contiguous space to hold all 100 integers (organized, as per C allocating method, as 10 arrays of 10 integers each in succession), in the second case will be allocated only an array of 10 pointers each pointing to the location of an array of 10 integers. And the 10 arrays **will not be allocated**, nor the pointers initialized.

In that case it is programmer responsibility to allocate 10 arrays of int and assign the address of each one to the array of pointers.

Another point to clarify (thanks to alk to have pointed it out) is that in the case of the array of pointers the second dimension is undefined, meaning that each array of `int` pointed can be of 1, 10, 1000 or whatever elements.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. So can an array like `int *array[10];` not be used as 2 dimensional? For example, no element exists at `array[0][0]`? EDIT: I see know you've addressed that, thanks

Comment: "*... each pointing to the location of 10 array of integers.*" hmm, no. These pointers point nowhere, as the array had not been initialised. And even if it were initialised in any case each element of `int * array[10]` pointed to an `int`, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @alk thanks. I corrected the typo and added some clarification. Unfortunately the subject of a language is always so large that whatever explanation you add there is always something wrong, a sentence unclear, missing or bad formed or the like. We should write  a book for each answer...

Answer (score 2):

`int *array[10];` is an array of 10 `int *`s, so the number of elements is 10.

To elaborate, for `int *array[10];`, ty type of `array` variable is `int * [10]`, an array of 10 elements of type pointer to integers.

The array size would be `10 * sizeof pointer-to-integer-in-your-platform`.

Answer (score 1):

> how many elements does array have?

```
 int *array[10];
```

`array` is array of 10 pointers to int, the same as `int* array[10]` - so `array` has 10 elements (each element being a pointer).